# Spelling correction on iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, text-input

How do I keep iOS from replacing my typing with something else when a correction is proposed? If I do nothing (i.e., don't choose the proposed word) and continue typing, it replaces the word I typed!

Is this possible to have the opposite behaviour—that is, to have to do something to have what I typed modified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Apple's iPod touch iOS4 User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPod_touch_iOS4_User_Guide.pdf). In particular, page 31 has two helpful tips:

> - To reject the suggested word, finish typing the word as you want it, then tap the “x” to dismiss the suggestion before typing anything else. Each time you reject a suggestion for the same word, iPod touch becomes more likely to accept your word.
> - Turn auto-correction and spell checking on or off: Choose General > Keyboard, then turn Auto-Correction on or off. Auto-Correction is on by default.

Comment: It's the first time I totally disagree with Apple UI. This is sooo annoying to have to have an eye on the top of the screen while your typing, to be sure the UI doesn't change what you type ;°)  I hope they will make some changes soon...